# How can I stop photos I download from popping up in Preview?

Tags: mac, download, photos

I download product photos from other websites and this happens:

1. I save the photo to the file I want
2. the photo then appears on Preview in the foreground on my Mac
3. the website I was downloading from has to be pulled up again from the        task bar.

This is quite annoying as I should be able to just download the photo and be right back on the website I was working on.

please advise as this must be a setting I'm missing out on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Safari… 
Prefs > General > uncheck Open "safe" files after downloading.

Alternatively, & imho far preferable, just have your destination folder visible next to your browser and just drag & drop pictures to it from the web site.

Comment: I use Chrome and don't see any setting on Preview or Chrome to stop this from happening but I'll try the drag and drop for a while and see how that works out.

Answer (score 0):

On Google Chrome, open preferences
at the side tab, click the dropdown. click on downloads.
you will see something about opening downloads, press clear.
Problem fixed.